# SQL Server : creating XML with child nodes for non unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I am having a hard time figuring out how to create an XML file from a SQL `select` that has sub nodes to store the not unique values.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

e.g.

```
select company, founder
from companies
```

The result of the query is:

```
 microsoft corp       Bill Gates
 microsoft corp       Paul Allen
 apple inc            Steve Jobs
 apple inc            Ronald Wayne
 apple inc            Steve Wozniak
```

I would like to generate an XML like

```
<values>
       <company>microsoft corp</company>
       <founders>
           <founder id="1">Bill Gates</founder>
           <founder id="2">Paul Allen</founder>
       </founders>
</values>
<values>
       <company>apple inc</company>
       <founders>
           <founder id="1">Steve Jobs</founder>
           <founder id="2">Ronald Wayne</founder>
           <founder id="3">Steve Wozniak</founder>
        </founders>
       </company>
</values>
```

I am not sure the node `<founders>` is required, I think it would also work fine for me to have the founders directly under the `<values>` node, since they keep in the right company, getting an id to have a list.

What I get right now, using `FOR XML`, then I tried different options is the following:

```
<values>
       <company>apple inc</company>
       <founder>Steve Jobs</founder>
</values>
<values>
       <company>apple inc</company>
       <founder>Ronald Wayne</founder>
</values>
<values>
       <company>apple inc</company>
       <founder>Steve Wozniak</founder>
</values>
```

which is not compatible with what I need to achieve then.

Any help to get all the founders under the same `<values>` node is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: just updated sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

Searched a bit internet and found solution:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (company VARCHAR(100), founder VARCHAR(100))

 insert into @table SELECT 'microsoft corp', 'Bill Gates'
 insert into @table SELECT 'microsoft corp', 'Paul Allen'
 insert into @table SELECT 'apple inc', 'Steve Jobs'
 insert into @table SELECT 'apple inc', 'Ronald Wayne'
 insert into @table SELECT 'apple inc', 'Steve Wozniak'


 SELECT company, 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER( ORDER BY founder ) as 'founder/@id',
            founder as 'founder'
        FROM @table as F
        WHERE F.company = Comp.company
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) AS founders
 FROM @table as Comp
 GROUP BY company
 FOR XML PATH('VALUES')
```

Result:

```
<VALUES>
  <company>apple inc</company>
  <founders>
    <founder id="1">Ronald Wayne</founder>
    <founder id="2">Steve Jobs</founder>
    <founder id="3">Steve Wozniak</founder>
  </founders>
</VALUES>
<VALUES>
  <company>microsoft corp</company>
  <founders>
    <founder id="1">Bill Gates</founder>
    <founder id="2">Paul Allen</founder>
  </founders>
</VALUES>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Companies TABLE (company VARCHAR(100), founder VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Companies VALUES
 ('microsoft corp',       'Bill Gates'),
 ('microsoft corp',       'Paul Allen'),
 ('apple inc',            'Steve Jobs'),
 ('apple inc',            'Ronald Wayne'),
 ('apple inc',            'Steve Wozniak')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT company
       ,(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Founder ASC)  AS [@ID] 
               ,B.founder [text()]
         FROM @companies B
        WHERE B.company = A.company
        FOR XML PATH('Founder'),TYPE) AS Founders
 FROM  @companies A
GROUP BY A.Company       
FOR XML PATH('values'),ROOT('Doc'), ELEMENTS
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<Doc>
  <values>
    <company>apple inc</company>
    <Founders>
      <Founder ID="1">Ronald Wayne</Founder>
      <Founder ID="2">Steve Jobs</Founder>
      <Founder ID="3">Steve Wozniak</Founder>
    </Founders>
  </values>
  <values>
    <company>microsoft corp</company>
    <Founders>
      <Founder ID="1">Bill Gates</Founder>
      <Founder ID="2">Paul Allen</Founder>
    </Founders>
  </values>
</Doc>
```